# How to print Json data to Django template

Tags: python, django

```
{
    '4': [1, 'Product New', '450.00', '4'], 
    '6': [1, 'Products Hello', '4500.00', '6']
}
```

I receive data in my view.py:

```
using products = json.loads(data)
```

After that, i am trying to show each item's in Django templates.
4 and 6 is pro

Comment: what did you get in your template?

Comment: i got like this json data in my template but how to parse ?? {'4': [1, 'Product New', '450.00', '4'], '6': [1, 'Products Hello', '4500.00', '6']}

Comment: You can try my answer, hope it will solve your issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can try this:**

```
data = {
    '4': [1, 'Product New', '450.00', '4'], 
    '6': [1, 'Products Hello', '4500.00', '6']
}

json_string = json.loads(data)
return render(request,'test.html',{'dataset':json_string})
```

**HTML Part:**

```
{% for key, value in dataset.items %}
{{key}}: {{value}}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: json_string = json.loads(data) working 
thank you